# How do I have mysql select statement case sensitive by default?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make mysql 8.0.11 query select case sensitive.

I'm aware mysql doesn't consider the case sensitivity by default.
For example, the following two statements yield the same result.

```
select * from user where username = 'u01';
select * from user where username = 'U01';
```

while, the following two do not

```
select * from user where username = BINARY 'u01';
select * from user where username = BINARY 'U01';
```

How do I have mysql select statement case sensitive by default as if I'm using `BINARY` without actually using `BINARY`?

I've tried create databases with collations that claim case sensitive

```
CREATE DATABASE cstest COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
CREATE DATABASE cstest COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

although none of them works. I have to explicitly using `BINARY` to distinguish 'u01' and 'U01' in my select statements.

Here is the table structure, automatically generated by spring data.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_login_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with which I have to use `BINARY` explicitly.

and then I tried this

```
ALTER TABLE user COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
```

and got

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_login_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_as_cs
```

with which I have to use `BINARY` explicitly again.

I also tried `utf8_general_cs` from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879861/ and got

> Unknown collation: 'utf8_general_cs'

How do I do? Any suggestions or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs in your DB should do it. Please add the SHOW CREATE TABLE of your table.

Comment: @MauricioCacho thank you. updated

Answer (score 0):

You changed the database *default* -- which is only used to provide the *default* for any newly created tables.  Also it provides the collation for future stored routines that you create.

If you are just changing a few columns, do

```
ALTER TABLE user
    MODIFY COLUMN username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
```

If you are changing all the char/text columns in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE user
    CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

(Similarly for utf8mb4_0900_as_cs if you chose that.)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE user MODIFY COLUMN username varchar(255) COLLATION utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL;` causes >>> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLLATION utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL' at line 1

Comment: Not `COLLATION` but `COLLATE`.